# Invoke .cmd file using variable name

Tags: powershell

The current PowerShell script invokes a .cmd file as follows:

```
cd $pathToCmdFile
.\Xyz.Web.deploy /y
```

I would like to change this so that Xyz is used as a variable, something like:

```
$webAppName = "Xyz"
cd $pathToCmdFile
.\$webAppName.Web.deploy /y
```

I've already tried

```
$cmd = ".\$webAppName.Web.deploy /y"
Invoke-Expression $cmd
```

Shows

> The term '.\Xyz.Web.deploy' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file or operable program...

I've also tried `Invoke-Command`, `Invoke-Item` but none seem to work. I have also tried putting an ampersand (`$cmd = "& .\$webAppName.Web.deploy /y"`), but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way of doing what you want is to use the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-3.0) (`&`). You must not include the operator or command arguments in the command string, though.

This should work:

```
$webAppName = "Xyz"
cd $pathToCmdFile
& ".\${webAppName}.Web.deploy.cmd" /y
```

I strongly recommend to always specify commands/scripts with their extension.

Comment: This is much simpler. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So `Invoke-Expressions` should work:

**`test.cmd`**

```
set
```

**`test.ps1` calls `test.cmd`**

```
cd .
$webAppName = "Test"
Invoke-Expression ".\\$webAppName.cmd"
```

So now you run the powershell script

```
> .\test.ps1
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
ANSICON=234x1000 (234x47)
ANSICON_DEF=7
...
```

Or you could do this so you can pass a parameter to the powershell script

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$webAppName
)
cd .
Invoke-Expression ".\\$webAppName.cmd"
```

Comment: Okay. I got that working. I should have specified in the original question that I was trying to run this on a remote computer (`Invoke-Command -Session $s ...`). The change directory (cd) was needed inside the script block running on the remote computer.

Comment: **[DO NOT USE `Invoke-Expression`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).**

Comment: Thanks Ansgar Wiechers